# Azimuth in android

Tags: android, gps, orientation, accelerometer, azimuth

I'm developping an app in which I'm getting the information from the orientation sensor. The only one I'm interested in is azimuth (or yaw).
The thing I dont understand is :

In which way is it recorded in regard of the phone. I made an schema of the way I think it's getting the azimuth but in the facts it doesn't seem to work like this. Could you enlighten me?

http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/2899/sanstitrerti.png[image: Azimuth in android]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this resource [here](http://androidprogramlama.com/tr/oryantasyon-ve-pusula-sensorleri-orientation-and-compass).

Use Google Chrome if you want it to be translated! :)

Comment: Thanks that helped !
So if I get it right, the way I was seeing it with my picture is not right at all, if I set my phone in the way of the picture the azimuth is not == 0 but more something like 90° right?